# optimisation for coefficients and for shifts

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find a way to solve an optimisation problem with R.

By way of example I have a 2D array or matrix, each column being a related set of points.  I have another set of data in a column that can be modelled as a weighted sum of the columns in the first matrix. (I use the term 'coefficients' for these weights)  The following R code shows an example solution to the type of problem I am trying to describe.

```
A=rbind(c(1.0, 1.0),c(1.0, 3.0),c(2.0, 2.0),c(4.0, 1.0),c(2.0, 1.0),c(1.0, 1.0))x
c=c(2.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.5, 2.5, 2.0)
x=qr.solve(A,c)

# this works and gives 0.5 and 1.5 for the two coefficients i.e c can be modelled as a weighted sum of teh columns in A, the weights being 0.5 and 1.5
```

however....

often my intial 2D array or matrix may have the values in the columns shifted up or down by a few positions.

for example I have shifted the second column by one position in the following example, shifts could be either up or down in a relative sense and they are usally small in terms of the number of points by which a column is shfted e.g < +/-10 in relation to the total number of points in a column (1000's).

```
A=rbind(c(1.0, 1.0),c(1.0, 1.0),c(2.0, 3.0),c(4.0, 2.0),c(2.0, 1.0),c(1.0, 1.0))
c=c(2.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.5, 2.5, 2.0)
x=qr.solve(A,c)
```

the fit obtained for the above is no longer the perfect fit of my first example because of the 'shift' of the data in the second column.  For real data is it clear that to get the best fits I need to optimise for the coefficients and also the shifts.

I am a complete newcomer to optimisation so I am a little bewildered by all the packages and approaches available.

So my question is how might I accomplish solving for the 'coefficients' and also for the 'shifts' to get the best possible fit to 'c' as a weighted sum of the column data in 'A'?

I hope my decription is claer and thank you in advance for any help or pointers.

Comment: Is there any cost associated with the shifts?

Comment: Sorry I don;t understand what 'cost' means?  The fits are improved if shifts are included in addition to optimising the coefficients, does that answer your question?

Comment: No it doesn't, quite. Are you saying that you can shift the columns up or down freely without there being any cost associated with those shifts? In many problems, changing things like this has some 'penalty cost' associated with this type of change. How many columns do you have, and how much can they each move? If there are not many columns, and they can only move +/- 10 places, then you could just enumerate all the possibilities and force just one of each set of variants of each column to be selected. If there are lots and shifts can be arbitrarily big, then you won't be able to do this.

Comment: Yes I would like the columns of data to be able to shft freely, though the shifts required for an improved fit are small >+/-10 points, relative to number of points in a column (1000's) and the bulk of the fitting of c by some weighted sum of the colums of A is down to finding the coefficients. Put another way I would like to solve for both the coeffcients (e.g 1.0, 0.7, 0.3, 2.5) and the shifts (e.g 1, 6, -4, 10).  In a real set of data there may be typically 20 to 30 columns of data in the matrix/2aray (A in example) that can be fit as a weighted sum to model (c).  will google 'cost'

Comment: Probably with 20 or 30 columns you could just create all the likely variants of each column (say +/- 10) which should give you a few hundred columns and it would then be a typical problem to optimise the coeffs. Maybe after that, you could try looking at shifting one or two columns by more than that to see if you can find some improvement.and then re-solve and repeat. Is there any structure in the columns? If there is then you might be able to get better clues by analysing the columns in more detail.

Comment: Ok many thanks for your help, I will investigate this approach of using pre shifted copies.

Comment: I suspect this can be solved using a MIQP (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming) solver. Quadratic so we can minimize the sum of squared errors and Mixed Integer to make sure we only select one lead or lag (not a combination).